# IntelliJ IDEA で自分で定義した .sh ファイル用の code snippet を登録・使用するには？

Tags: intellij-idea

これまで Eclipse を使っていて、これから IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE を利用し始めようとしているものです。

プロジェクトの中にある .sh のファイルを編集するために、BashSupport プラグインをインストールして、編集してみているところなのですが、例えば if 構文などが`Ctrl+Space`で補完されてくれないことに気づきました。

ないものは仕方がないだろうと、 .sh 用の snippet を自分で定義しようとしたのですが、何をどういじったらいいのかわかりません。

どうやったら、自分の .sh 用の snippet を定義・登録し、使用することができるでしょうか。

2016/01/28 追記: 先ほど確認したところ、 if 文は補完できてました。おかしいな。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferences -> Editor -> Live Templatesで定義できます。

右横の+ボタンから適当なTemplate Groupを作成し、その中にLive Templateを作成し、入れていきます。

このとき、初期状態ではどのファイル形式で使うLive Templateかが未定義になっています（No applicable contexts yet.というエラーが表示されます）ので、エラーの右横に表示されるDefineからファイル形式を指定します。

対象のファイル形式がない場合は、同じくPreferencesのFile Typesから追加することができます。

詳しくはヘルプを参照してください。
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-templates.html

Comment: for 文はなかったのでそれを登録してみました。問題なく動作しました。